# getting the content of a .csv using open csv

Tags: java, opencsv

How to get and display some lines of a csv using openCSV.
I currently have the following code :

```
CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(mydata_csv.getpath()));
List myDatas = reader1.readAll();
```

How to display one specific line ?

Maybe can I use a better way to store my datas (the csv contains lines of hundreds variables). any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for opencsv http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read seems to say that your code returns a list of String[]

in which case I would write it like so:

```
CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(mydata_csv.getpath()));
List<String[]> myDatas = reader1.readAll();
String[] lineI = myDatas.get(i);
for (String[] line : myDatas) {
    for (String value : line) {
        //do stuff with value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have never used List. So now, I know how to use open CSV in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(mydata_csv.getpath()));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```